# php-mcrypt package missing from yum on AWS AMI

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, yum, php-mcrypt

Seems like new versions of the Amazon AMI on EC2 don't have the php-mcrypt package available. How do I get it?

```
$ sudo yum install php-mcrypt
Loaded plugins: langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core
No package php-mcrypt available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

In general, how do I figure out how to solve "missing packages" problems like this?

Comment: Explicitly setting the version is not a solution. `php54-` packages are also all missing.

Comment: `sudo yum info php` and `php -v` indicate version is `php 5.4.16`

Comment: They don't ship it. Use something other than Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to install `php-mcrypt` following the suggestion [on this page](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=270511) using EPEL for EL 7 into AWS release 2.0 (2017.12) Linux.

This is an Amazon instance running Amazon Linux 2 (2017.12) which I tested with...

```
# cat /etc/system-release
Amazon Linux release 2.0 (2017.12) LTS Release Candidate
# curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id
ami-428aa838
```

The people at amazon claim that AWS distro is [not based specifically](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=51647) on any version of RedHat, **so there is no guarantee of compatibility**, but comparing the versions of the PHP packages in EPEL for Enterprise linux 7, and the amazon ones, suggests they are building from the same source;

for example the build numbers are exactly the same `Version     : 5.4.16` on the packages from `amzn2-core` and `epel`

```
Name        : php-mcrypt
Version     : 5.4.16
Release     : 7.el7
From repo   : epel
```

vs

```
Name        : php
Version     : 5.4.16
Release     : 43.amzn2.0.1
From repo   : amzn2-core
```

So I am not surprised the package from epel installed on the 2017.12 AWS AMI no problem...

```
# yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
...
  Installing : epel-release-7-11.noarch        1/1
  Verifying  : epel-release-7-11.noarch        1/1

Installed:
  epel-release.noarch 0:7-11

Complete!
```

and then installed `php-mcrypt`;

```
# yum install -y --enablerepo=epel php-mcrypt
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : libmcrypt-2.5.8-13.el7.x86_64      1/2 
  Installing : php-mcrypt-5.4.16-7.el7.x86_64     2/2 
  Verifying  : libmcrypt-2.5.8-13.el7.x86_64      1/2 
  Verifying  : php-mcrypt-5.4.16-7.el7.x86_64     2/2 

Installed:
  php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.4.16-7.el7                                                                                                    

Dependency Installed:
  libmcrypt.x86_64 0:2.5.8-13.el7                                                                                                     

Complete!
```

and then you can test to see that mcrypt extensions is installed like so;

```
# php -i "(command-line 'phpinfo()')" | grep mcrypt
/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini,
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
```

I also disabled epel, as I don't want to end up with a mix of packages from both repos beyond the minimum;

```
yum-config-manager --disablerepo=epel



# yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: langpacks, priorities, update-motd
repo id                      repo name                                                                  status
amzn2-core/2017.12/x86_64    Amazon Linux 2 core       enabled: 7,157
epel/x86_64                  Extra Packages            disabled
```

Comment: Be careful. Amazon Linux 2 _might_ be forked from CentOS 7, but that doesn't mean compatibility is guaranteed. This has historically been a serious problem with Amazon Linux. If you want to be sure of compatibility, just save yourself a lot of trouble and go with CentOS 7.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I only span the instance up to do the test! Currently most of my work is migrating from EL6 to EL7 using ansible...

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching it a lot and got it working.

Try This.

```
# amazon-linux-extras install epel
# yum install php-mcrypt
```

Comment: The same compatibility warning applies here. You should expect this to break in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Found an even easier solution. Just run:

```
yum install php-pecl-mcrypt
```

This works for PHP 7.3 and on Amazon Linux 2